# Regex: How can I catch big numbers with spaces in them?

Tags: python, regex, recursion, regex-recursion

I'm trying to catch all numbers from a string using Python regex. By numbers I mean integers and floats (using `,` or `.`).
I managed to get it done using this regex : `([0-9]+[\,|\.][0-9]+|[0-9]+)`

But I have a problem, I need it to match big numbers with spaces in them. I mean `20 000` or `5 000 000`. And these numbers can be very big with a lot of spaces. I don't know how much. But there will always be 1 space between numbers, no more. For example: `20    30` = this will be 2 differents numbers.

I guess I will need some sort of recursive pattern `(?R)`, but I don't know how to use it.

Can someone help ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pattern like

```py
(?<!\d)(?<!\d[.,])\d{1,3}(?:\s\d{3})*(?:[,.]\d+)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7D7g7V/2/).

*Details*

- `(?<!\d)(?<!\d[.,])` - no digit or digit plus a comma or period immediately to the left of the current location are allowed
- `\d{1,3}` - one, two or three digits
- `(?:\s\d{3})*` - zero or more sequences of a whitespace and three digits
- `(?:[,.]\d+)?` - an optional occurrence of a `,` or `.` and then one or more digits.

In [Python](https://ideone.com/OssWGV), you can use `re.findall`:

```py
import re
text = "5 000, 6 123 456,345 and 6 123 456.345... I mean 20 000 or 5 000 000. For example: 20    30"
print( re.findall(r'(?<!\d)(?<!\d[.,])\d{1,3}(?:\s\d{3})*(?:[,.]\d+)?', text) )
## => ['5 000', '6 123 456,345', '6 123 456.345', '20 000', '5 000 000', '20', '30']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
number='20 300  4 100   400  50'
res=re.findall(r'(\d*\s*)',number)
res=''.join(res).split('  ')
print(list(map(lambda x: int(x.replace(' ','')),res)))
```

-output

`[20300, 4100, 400, 50]`

Comment: This doesn't work for the OP's case of multiple numbers separated by multiple spaces, e.g. `number='20  3000   400` should give `('20', '3000', '400')` but will give `'203000400'`

Comment: You'll need a further enhancement to cover the OP's case of a long number with digits separated by a single space and grouped in triples, e.g. `number= '20 300  4 100   400  50'` should give `['20 300', '4 100',  '400', '50']` vs. your current answer that will give `['20', '300', '4', '100', '400', '50']`. (Although I suspect that `['20300', '4100', '400', '50']` would be acceptable too.)